# How to automate html5 ui tests

Tags: html, ui-automation

I have been using Xcode’s instruments for running UI automation on IOS apps our team have been developing. I’ve just been asked to start UI testing on some HTML5 android apps and have been looking ways to achieve this. Our user base will only be able to use Google chrome. 
I have looked at Selenium but  this seems to be a Firefox add-on and Firefox is not allowed to be loaded onto our development PC’s. I have looked at various other alternatives but have come to the conclusion that it’s best to get recommendations from people who use it

Can anyone suggest a solution that is equivalent to Xcode’s i.e.:-

1. Record a UI journey through an app
2. Identify that icons, buttons fields etc exist on a screen
3. Identify the positions of icons,buttons etc on a screen
4. Returns a log of each run